# How to blacklist and whitelist users in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Hi I am trying to make whitelist and blacklist commands by which I can blacklist users from using my bot, I am using postgreSQL and I have successfully made the command to store user id and the reason to blacklist the user , I just want to know how can I make a global check or something like that so that bot checks the blacklisted_users table before processing every command and returns if the author id is in blacklisted users.
Sorry I can't provide with what I tried , because Idk actually where to start. I just want to know the basic syntax of this kind of global check, I can handle rest.
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [API docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=check#discord.ext.commands.Bot.check) for `Bot.check`:

> A decorator that adds a global check to the bot.
>
> A global check is similar to a check() that is applied on a per
> command basis except it is run before any command checks have been
> verified and applies to every command the bot has.
>
> Similar to a command check(), this takes a single parameter of type
> Context and can only raise exceptions inherited from CommandError.

This means that you'll first have to write a function that either checks if `ctx author.id` is in your `blacklist` table, or a function that returns every `id` in your blacklist in a `list`.

```
@Bot.check()
def blacklist_check(ctx):
    blacklisted = [] # Write a function that gets every blacklisted user's ID from your database
    return ctx.author.id not in blacklisted # Checks if the author is in your blacklist
```